# Redirection 301 with htaccess with url variables

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've searched answers on the forum but didn't worked for me.

I have rebuild an website using Wordpress and want to keep old urls.

I have old URLs like : `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=51&Itemid=67&lang=fr`

that i want to move permanantly to url like : `/produits-et-services/conseil-et-accompagnement/`

Redirect 301 didn't worked because of vars in URL.. and i've try this  :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=51&Itemid=67&lang=fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://solunea.fr/produits-et-services/conseil-et-accompagnement/ [L,R=301]
```

On my wordpress `.htaccess` but didn't worked either.

Can someone help me please ??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=51&Itemid=67&lang=fr$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /produits-et-services/conseil-et-accompagnement/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

is placed right on top **before any other existing rewrite rule**

and test in a different browser to avoid 301 caching issues.